# Adding probability density functions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

I've just started studying probability, so I beg your pardon if my question is silly.

Consider a pdf $\large p_{f}(x)$, for a continuous random variable, that represents the distribution of images of all possible human faces. Now, this distribution is made up of many types of unique features, for instance faces with glasses, women, men, beard, no beard, and so on... For simplicity, let's say I'm only interested in "beard" with its own pdf $\large p_{b}$ and "no beard" with its own pdf $\large p_{nb}$.

Now, **no human face can exist out of these two distributions**, this implies the pdf $\large p_{f}(x)$ can be written only with $\large p_{b}(x)$ and $\large p_{nb}(x)$.

So how can I write $\large p_{f}(x)$ in terms of $\large p_{b}(x)$ and $\large p_{nb}(x)$ only?

If I'm talking about a discrete RV, then ofc it's simply the addition of pmf of these "beard" and "no beard" distributions. Which is not the case. So how can I add these two pdfs?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is not clear.  You are imagining that the space of all possible  human faces exists as some big space, like $\mathbb R^n$ for some large $n$, or something like that...yes?  And of course there is a probability distribution on that space...after all, brown eyes are more probable that bright yellow eyes and so on.  Fair enough.  But, then, you introduce some binary characteristic and claim you can build the entire distribution if you just know this one characteristic?  How could that be?

Comment: I'm just coming from discrete RVs, maybe that's why I'm messing it up. Actually, I'm thinking in terms of Venn diagram, like if the universal set is divided into two subsets (where they both would be the complement of each other), then the addition of these two subsets is the universal set. I'm trying to find some sort of scenario but in terms of pdf.

Comment: Well, you haven't described the sample space.  You must have some "universal" probability measure $d\mu$ on the space and then, writing the two binary cases as $f_+(x) d\mu$ and $f_-(x)d\mu$ we get that $f_+(x)+f_-(x)=1$.  Just as in the finite case.  But the hard part is to describe the sample space and the various probabilities attached to that.

Comment: Okay, lemme ask the original que in another way, if I know $\large p_{f}$ and $\large p_{b}$ mathematically very well, then is it possible to write $\large p_{nb}$ in terms of those two? Knowing that all RVs sampled from $\large p_{nb}$ are part of $\large p_{f}$.

Comment: Well, depending on exactly what you mean, you could just have $p_b+p_{nb}=p_f$.  But, really, the hard thing here is to describe exactly what space you are talking about.

Comment: If I describe the $\large p_{f}(x)$ as the pdf of weight measurements **of all humans**. And $\large p_{b}(x)$ as the pdf of weight measurements **of men**, and I know both of them mathematically exactly, then does it describe what space I'm talking about?

Comment: Not really.  Focus on the sample space.  If you can describe that clearly then the answer to your question should be obvious.  As I say, a large part of the difficulty in these sorts of things comes down to clearly stating what it is you mean.

Comment: Not sure that this is what you mean, but:  if you knew the weight distribution for a randomly selected male and you knew the weight distribution for a randomly selected female AND you knew the probability that a randomly selected individual was male or female (for this problem, assume that's a binary matter)  then you can reconstruct the weight distribution for a randomly selected individual.  (here assume that "randomly selected" means uniformly random.  That's ok as long as you have a finite set of people).

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for staying with me here, really appreciate it. Actually, I don't want to compute anything or come up with any numerical value as answer. All I want is to come up with a mathematical statement, for $\large p_{f}(x)$, $\large p_{b}(x)$ and $\large p_{nb}(x)$, knowing that $\large p_{b}(x)$ and $\large p_{nb}(x)$ are complementary, and all RVs sampled from $\large p_{b}(x)$ and $\large p_{nb}(x)$ are part of $\large p_{f}(x)$, or in other words all those RVs can also be sampled from $\large p_{f}(x)$. So now, is it okay to write $\large p_{f}(x) = p_{b}(x) + p_{nb}(x)$?

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, you need to be clear about what your sample space is and what these functions mean.  If, in your original problem, you mean for your sample space to consist of the collection of possible face types, then, if $x$ is a possible face type then we know whether type $x$ has a beard or not.  There isn't any probability involved, since having a beard (or not) is part of the definition of $x$.

Comment: Got you, though could you instead provide me with an example scenario when an expression like $\large p_{f}(x) = p_{b}(x) + p_{nb}(x)$ would be 100% foolproof?

Comment: For a set $E$ in the $\sigma$ algebra attached yo your distribution, let $\mu_b(E)$ denote the probability that a randomly selected individual  is of face type contained in $E$ AND has a beard.  Similarly $\mu_{nb}(E)$.  Then the sum of these is $\mu(E)$.  The probability that a randomly selected individual has face type contained in $E$.  I think that's the statement you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked the same question in multiple ways ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986150/converting-discrete-probability-scenario-into-probability-density-functions), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986472/combining-multiple-probability-density-functions) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986472/combining-multiple-probability-density-functions/3986534#3986534)) so that someone would get my doubt. And finally, thanks to [jlammy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/304635/jlammy) who provided the perfect answer to the question.

What I was looking for, was the mixture distribution, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20and%20statistics%2C%20a,then%20the%20value%20of%20the) its explained really really well.
The combination of density functions can be written as their weighted sum. Where the weights are their corresponding proportions in the population.

[image]

So in my above case, the $\large p_{f}(x)$ can simply be written as $\large p * p_{b}(x) + (1 - p) * p_{nb}$, where $\large p$ denotes the proportion of bearded humans, and $\large (1 - p)$ denotes the proportion of non bearded humans.

Comment: Guys, if my posted answer is wrong in any way then please let me know.