# Combining multiple probability density functions.

Tags: probability, convolution, density-function

I'm trying so hard to clear out my simple confusion but I'm getting nowhere near to it :(

Let's say, the PDF for weight measurement of all adults (age $\ge$ 18) is given $\large p_{adults}$, using this, I can tell what's the probability that an adult person would weigh between a Kgs to b Kgs...

And the PDF for weight measurement of all non-adults (age $\lt $ 18) is given $\large p_{non-adults}$, and using this, I can tell what's the probability that a non-adult person would weigh between c Kgs to d Kgs...

Since **all humans is either an adult or not**... can't I find a PDF that would represent the weight measurement of all humans? Or in other words, what would be a single PDF such that can cover all the cases of $\large p_{adults}(x)$ and $\large p_{non-adults}(x)$?

If this is possible to find then how?? If not then why not??

I am thinking that the answer should be yes, and that single PDF might be represented by some operation between $\large p_{adults}(x)$ and $\large p_{non-adults}(x)$, like addition or multiplication, or maybe convolution or something like that... what would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the law of total probability. Let $F_A$ and $F_C$ be the cumulative distribution functions for the weights of adults and children, respectively. If the proportion of adults in the population is $p$, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X\leq x)&=\mathbb P(X\leq x\mid\text{Adult})\cdot\mathbb P(\text{Adult})+\mathbb P(X\leq x\mid\text{Child})\cdot\mathbb P(\text{Child})\\
&=pF_A(x)+(1-p)F_C(x).
\end{align*}
Differentiating implies that the density is given by $f(x)=pf_A(x)+(1-p)f_C(x)$.

This is a relatively simple example of *mixture distributions*.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @jlammy, you made my day. Just a final confirmation before I celebrate, the $f(x)$ you computed is the density function for the whole population right?

Comment: Yes of course :)

Comment: Seriously dude, I just couldn't thank you enough. I spent full two days for this doubt... Asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985091/adding-probability-density-functions), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986150/converting-discrete-probability-scenario-into-probability-density-functions), but wasn't getting anything. And I can't believe the answer was this simple. Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: Hello again jlammy, just a follow-up question, is there a way to intuitively interpret the expression $\large \frac{pf_{A}(x)}{f(x)}$ based one the above formulations?